# Socket io and closures in a loop

Tags: javascript, socket.io, closures

I wan to simplify the following code:

```
socket.on('event1', function(data){
    func1(data);
});
....
socket.on('eventN', function(data){
    funcN(data);
});
```

So I tried to create and object

```
var socketsMap = {
    event1      : func1,
    ...,
    eventN      : funcN
}
```

And I thought that I have done closures correctly with

```
for (var event in socketsMap){
    socket.on(event, function(data){
        return function(data){
            socketsMap[event](data);
        };
    });
}
```

but apparently I am missing something as only the last one is always executed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: I have given an answer what worked for me, I am creating a template for your specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:-

```
var socketsMap = {};

socketsMap['event1'] = function (data) {
  //code
}
.....

socketsMap['eventN'] = function (data) {
  //code 
}

for (var event in socketsMap){
    socket.on(event, socketsMap[event]);
}
```